# Swift - Отобразить UI после загрузки данных

Tags: многопоточность, swift

Понимаю, что вопрос туп, но прошу простить - только пытаюсь разобраться в Swift.

У меня имеется экран с tablewView (в каждой ячейке - картинка и некоторый текст). Информацию для таблицы я получаю из JSON файла, который парсится при каждом открытии экрана. Но, естественно, это занимает определенное время (особенно загрузка картинок) и таблица никак не ждет, что я распарсю данные и отдам их ей - она отображается пустой.

Понимаю, что нужно копать куда-то в сторону потоков и очередей, но но не могу сообразить куда именно.

Нид хэлп)

Comment: Доброго вечера, не понимаю вашу проблему, у вас во время загрузки UI тормозит? И вставьте пожалуйста в вопрос ваш код реализации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После завершения загрузки данных стоит запустить обновление таблицы с помощью `tableView.reloadData()`.  Если парсинг данных происходит в отдельной очереди, то стоит не забыть перевести выполнение в главную:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Если у вас написано использование загруженных данных и отображение ячеек, то после этого метода все данные отобразятся.